# rsyslog with variable input file name

Tags: apache-2.2, rsyslog

I am running an apache server which is creating log files using *rotatelogs*.
It creates a new file every day with the date appended to it (e.g. filename.yyyy.mm.dd format).

I want to use rsyslog to transfer these logs to a common server but the problem is that variable $InputFileName of Module *imFile* requires the actual path and doesn't accept any variable or template name.

How do I provide a variable name to $InputFileName so that it automatically sends the log of the new file generated by *rotatelogs* everyday?

Answer (score 0):

You could have Apache write to a file at a set path, have rsyslog read that file, and occasionally rotate that file using [logrotate](https://fedorahosted.org/logrotate/).